# matching content creating new column

Tags: python, pandas, function

Hello I have a dataset where I want to match my keyword with the location.  The problem I am having is the location "Afghanistan" or "Kabul" or "Helmund" I have in my dataset appears in over 150 combinations including spelling mistakes, capitalization and having the city or town attached to its name.  What I want to do is create a separate column that returns the value 1 if any of these characters "afg" or "Afg" or "kab" or "helm" or "are contained in the location. I am not sure if upper or lower case makes a difference.

For instance there are hundreds of location combinations like so: Jegdalak, Afghanistan, Afghanistan,Ghazni♥, Kabul/Afghanistan,

I have tried this code and it is good if it matches the phrase exactly but there is too much variation to write every exception down

```
keywords= ['Afghanistan','Kabul','Herat','Jalalabad','Kandahar','Mazar-i-Sharif', 'Kunduz', 'Lashkargah', 'mazar', 'afghanistan','kabul','herat','jalalabad','kandahar']


#how to make a column that shows rows with a certain keyword..
def keyword_solution(value):
    strings = value.split()
    if any(word in strings for word in keywords):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

taleban_2['keyword_solution'] = taleban_2['location'].apply(keyword_solution)

# below will return the 1 values

taleban_2[taleban_2['keyword_solution'].isin(['1'])].head(5)
```

Just need to replace this logic where all results will be put into column "keyword_solution" that matches either "Afg" or "afg" or "kab" or "Kab" or "kund" or "Kund"

Answer (score 0):

### Given the following:

- Sentences from the New York Times
- Remove all non-alphanumeric characters
- Change everything to lowercase, thereby removing the need for different word variations
- Split the sentence into a `list` or `set`.  I used `set` because of the long sentences.
- Add to the `keywords` list as needed
- Matching words from two lists

  - `'afgh' in ['afghanistan']`: `False`
  - `'afgh' in 'afghanistan'`: `True`
  - Therefore, the list comprehension searches for each keyword, in each word of `word_list`.
  - `[True if word in y else False for y in x for word in keywords]`
  - This allows the list of keywords to be shorter (i.e. given `afgh`, `afghanistan` is not required)

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

keywords= ['jalalabad',
           'kunduz',
           'lashkargah',
           'mazar',
           'herat',
           'mazar',
           'afgh',
           'kab',
           'kand']

df = pd.DataFrame({'sentences': ['The Taliban have wanted the United States to pull troops out of Afghanistan Turkey has wanted the Americans out of northern Syria and North Korea has wanted them to at least stop military exercises with South Korea.',
                                 'President Trump has now to some extent at least obliged all three — but without getting much of anything in return. The self-styled dealmaker has given up the leverage of the United States’ military presence in multiple places around the world without negotiating concessions from those cheering for American forces to leave.',
                                 'For a president who has repeatedly promised to get America out of foreign wars, the decisions reflect a broader conviction that bringing troops home — or at least moving them out of hot spots — is more important than haggling for advantage. In his view, decades of overseas military adventurism has only cost the country enormous blood and treasure, and waiting for deals would prolong a national disaster.',
                                 'The top American commander in Afghanistan, Gen. Austin S. Miller, said Monday that the size of the force in the country had dropped by 2,000 over the last year, down to somewhere between 13,000 and 12,000.',
                                 '“The U.S. follows its interests everywhere, and once it doesn’t reach those interests, it leaves the area,” Khairullah Khairkhwa, a senior Taliban negotiator, said in an interview posted on the group’s website recently. “The best example of that is the abandoning of the Kurds in Syria. It’s clear the Kabul administration will face the same fate.”',
                                 'afghan']})

# substitute non-alphanumeric characters
df['sentences'] = df['sentences'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('[\W_]+', ' ', x))

# create a new column with a list of all the words
df['word_list'] = df['sentences'].apply(lambda x: set(x.lower().split()))

# check the list against the keywords
df['location'] = df.word_list.apply(lambda x: any([True if word in y else False for y in x for word in keywords]))

# final
print(df.location)

0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
Name: location, dtype: bool
```